# Tabs within Tabs using Jquery and Bootstrap, inner tabs not filling to width

Tags: jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, twitter-bootstrap

So I am working on a project that is using Bootstrap tabs, inside one of these tabs is a thin on the left and another tab control on the right.

Now the inner tabs will not fill the rest of the width to the right side of the screen leaving a big gap. (Illustrated below )

Now i want to eliminate the gap marked by the red arrow and have the inner tab fill that space.

[image]

Here is how the actually HTML looks inside the outer tab group

```
<div id="container">
<div id="leftpane">
    <div id="circles-active" class="circle">
        // Display Graph
    </div>      
</div>
<div id="rightpane">
    <div id="rightpane-inner">
                // Display Inner Tab Group  
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your CSS, it is difficult to say what is pushing over the inner set of tabs.

If you have `margin` or `margin-right` set in your CSS for `rightpane`, this could cause the problem.

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mccannf/3VBym/7/) shows how it is possible to have a fixed header and fixed left pane and the rest of the screen scrolls with the page.